# How to increment IP by 1 batch

Tags: batch-file

```
@echo off
set /p IP1=Enter IP address: 
set SM=255.255.255.255
set IP2=%IP1%

netsh interface ip set address "Ethernet" static %IP2% %SM% %IP1%
pause 
goto end
:B
```

I'm trying to set a static IP through batch file. I'm having the user prompt for the gateway IP and increment by 1 (the last octet of IP)

For example

User input 10.10.10.10

IP address 10.10.10.11
Gateway 10.10.10.10

Answer (score 0):

You would have to split up the IP address into separate variables.  You can easily do that with a `FOR /F` command by using the period as a delimiter.

```
FOR /F "tokens=1-4 delims=." %%A IN (%IP1%) DO (
    set octet1=%%A
    set octet2=%%B
    set octet3=%%C
    set octet4=%%D
)
set /A octet4+=1
set IP2=%octet1%.%octet2%.%octet3%.%octet4%
```